# Raphael 100% paper is giving me a vertical scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, raphael, vertical-scrolling

I've been using the Raphael library and have encountered an odd issue.

My test HTML contains only a div with an ID of "main". My CSS is simply-

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#main {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I can add more stuff to the HTML without any scrollbars appearing. But, as soon as I add-

```
var paper = Raphael("main", "100%", "100%");
```

I get a vertical bar. Does anyone have any insight as to why? If I set it to "98%" it goes away, and I am willing to accept that as a quick and dirty workaround, but I like to know the why's of everything. Plus, who knows how that will react to different platforms.

Comment: as Johnny 5 says: "Need - More - Input"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, I really couldn't figure out "why"!

But I've created a fiddle with your issue (http://jsfiddle.net/Z8dYT/), and by coloring the div and body it's possible to see that the div is still the correct height. Just the body is a little overflowed.

If that's ok for you, just add a `overflow:hidden` to the body, and it will be all right. Otherwise, at least I hope the fiddle will be handy =)

Comment: Hmm.. This does work in jsfiddle (thanks for that, by the way), but the changes have no effect when I load my local copy in Chrome.

Changing to FF, the bar does not appear when using 100%, or the CSS change, but it seems to ignore all my transformation changes when I set the height and width of the paper to 100%. Which, is not really part of this problem, but it now makes me think that going with straight hardcoded pixels rather than percentages is what I might have to do.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. That did work. I umm... forgot to link the CSS. >.> All this time... dammit :c And that seemed to have solved my FF problem, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it might be an issue with box-sizing. Try this:

```
#main {
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

A jsfiddle helps so much, by the way. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Haha, I did actually mean to add a jsfiddle, but I thought it might be one of those questions that has an obvious answer that I was just missing.